# Does Google Mobile Vision support OCR on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-vision

I'm looking at using Google Mobile Vision with an iOS app. Their documentation talks about face recognition, barcode scanning, and text recognition (OCR). However, the code samples for iOS development only include facial recognition, and I don't see anything in the API documentation for iOS other than facial recognition support.

Is it the case that they only support OCR and barcode scanning on Android?

If this were the case, I would have expected that fact to be clearly stated somewhere in the introduction to the product or the getting started page, but it is not, which surprises me, and leaves me wondering whether I'm just confused and not finding it.

Thanks.

Comment: I have having the same confusion. My application needs Google Translation Camera mode functionality and I am confused how to approach.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41382396/ios-google-vision-api-text-detection-as-like-google-camera-translate-ios-app .

Comment: Did you get the correct answer?

Comment: Did u get any alternative ways?

Answer (score 2):

The Google Mobile Vision website at the time of this post says:

> Note that iOS supports only face detection and tracking at this time.

Source: https://developers.google.com/vision/reference

Answer (score 1):

In March 2017, it find faces and barcodes in photos and videos.

https://developers.google.com/vision/ios/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2018 it does support text recognition however in I/O 2018 Google deprecated it in favor of ML.Kit which is part of Firebase.  ML.kit supports both cloud and on device text recognition.